# Why am I receiving this Template error in my django tutorial?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently working through the django polls tutorial and I keep receiving this error. I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

I have tried watching multiple youtube tutorials, searched on stack for users having the same problem, and I can't seem to get anything to work.

Any and all help would be much appreciated. Thanks guys

[my_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiG6Q.png)

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY9RF.png)

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShLtd.png)

[urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyuzD.png)

Comment: what error ? Please add the template example and the traceback

Comment: You should try posting code in place of screenshot of code.

Comment: together with the *full* traceback...

Comment: maybe in settings.py in templates section in dirs you have to add os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a type mistake while sending the template name in detail view.

```
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question':question})
```

You have set the template name as `'polls/detail.html'` but your template is `details.html` in your file.

Rename the template file to `detail.html` and it will work fine.